# How to add a variable value to an existing table value in SQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I think you will be able to solve this fast. Its probably a syntax error on my part. I have a table "guild" and I am trying to update a value "points". I think there is something wrong with the syntax. Anyone able to help?

```
$guild = $_POST["guild"];
$pointsToAdd = $_POST["pointsAdd"];

$updatePointsQuery = "UPDATE guild SET points = points + " . $pointsToAdd . " WHERE name = '" . $guild . "';";
mysqli_query($con, $updatePointsQuery) or die("error code #4: points could not be updated"); //error 4 insert query failed
```

error code: [31-Jan-2019 09:03:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in E:\MAMP\htdocs\sqlconnect\addclanpoint.php on line 21

Comment: The things I note are, you're not validating any of the POST fields, you're directly concat-ing user data into SQL queries instead of using prepared statements with parameters, and you don't appear to be running the query. You have to explain what the problem is and provide all relevant code for us to be able to help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error you get as well as the code mentioned by the error

Comment: just added the query. I dont have a debugger setup so I dont know what the error msg is. I was hoping it would be obvious

Comment: You don't need a debugger. Just make sure you have `error_reporting` turned on and check your servers error log for info. You can also enable `display_errors` while you're debugging the code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson oh wow! Thanks I didnt know that haha. Here is the error message i found:
[31-Jan-2019 09:03:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in E:\MAMP\htdocs\sqlconnect\addclanpoint.php on line 21

Comment: What line is 21?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson line 21 is:
 $updatePointsQuery = "UPDATE guild SET points = " . $currentPoints + $pointsToAdd . " WHERE name = '" . $guild . "'";

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i figured it out. Thanks for your effort though. If you want to post a sol'n I can give you an accepted answer. the solution was just this:

 $updatePointsQuery = "UPDATE guild SET points = points + " . $pointsToAdd . " WHERE name = '" . $guild . "'";

i think i may have been putting an incorrect value through my C# script maybe...

Answer (score 0):

I assume the points in the string is a table column. You firstly need to get the points and place them in a variable

```
$guild = $_POST["guild"];
$pointsToAdd = $_POST["pointsAdd"];

$currentPoints = "SELECT points FROM guild WHERE name = '" . $guild . "'";

$updatePointsQuery = "UPDATE guild SET points = " . $currentPoints + $pointsToAdd . " WHERE name = '" . $guild . "'";
```

Comment: **Warning!** This code is _highly_ insecure since it's _wide open_ to SQL injections. Don't concatenate your queries like that. Specially since it's unescaped user data. Use parameterized prepared statements instead.

Comment: Just tried your solution, im still getting an error on $updatePointsQuery though. $currentPoints and $pointsToAdd are both integers if that helps.

Comment: @CameronRoberson - _"im still getting an error"_. Please share what error you're getting.

Comment: _“You firstly need to get the points and place them in a variable”_ - no you don’t, stuff like `UPDATE foo SET points = points + 3` works perfectly fine for such situations.